# variable in indexing pandas dataframe problem

Tags: python, pandas

I can use this code

```
df.loc[0 :4,"strength"]
```

and I get pandas series with no problem. but I can't use this code

```
upbound  = 0
lowbound = 4
df.loc[lowbound :upbound ,"strength"]
```

and I get empty pandas series. so why is that? is it some sort of python version problem? I have *python 3.7.6* . will the

```
upbound  = 0
lowbound = 4
df.ix[lowbound :upbound ,"strength"]
```

work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason here is the up and low opposite

```
lowbound = 0
upbound = 4
df.loc[lowbound :upbound ,"strength"]
```

Comment: I would do that in 5 mins